# Averaging multiple netCDF4 files with python

Tags: python, numpy, average, netcdf4

I am a bit of a netCDF in python noob so please excuse this noob question.

I have a folder filled with circa 3650 netCDF4 files. One file per day for a decade. the niles are named yyyymmdd.nc (e.g. 20100101,20100102,20100103,etc.). Each .nc file contains latitude, longitude, and temperature at one-time point for the same area - a section of the Tonga EEZ.

What I am trying to do is compute the average temperature for each lat and lon from across all files, i.e. I want to end up with one .nc file that has all the same lats and lons and average temperature across 10 years.

I have tried different things/versions of code, usually, they end up looking something like this.....

```
files = glob('*.nc')
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(files,)
mean = np.mean(ds['temp'][:, 0].values)
```

...... This code would give me the average temperature within a .nc file for all .nc files and not the average temperature based on lat and lon across a decade worth of files.

All and any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have feeling that `mean = np.mean(ds['temp'][:, 0].values)` is not good approach as you already then cut some data. What are the dimensions of ds['temp']? Does the `mean = np.mean(ds['temp'][:].values,axis=0)` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working on linux/macOS, this can be done easily using my nctoolkit package(see details [here](https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/)).

The following will calculate the mean across all files and then plot the results:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
files = glob('*.nc')
ds = nc.open_data(file)
ds.ensemble_mean()
ds.plot()
```

nctoolkit uses CDO as a back-end by default, but can use NCO as well, which can result in a performance improvement. So the following might be faster:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
files = glob('*.nc')
ds = nc.open_data(file)
ds.ensemble_mean(nco=True)
ds.plot()
```

Comment: this works like a charm. thumbs up for nctoolkit.

Comment: Hi Robert.  again thanks for introducing me to this. nctookit is really making things easier for me. I have a quick follow-up question.  using ds.ensemble can I also calculate the standard deviation. I have tried ds.ensemble_stdev(nco=True) but this errors out with stdev not found.

Comment: Thanks. At the minute no. But I can implement this relatively easily. If you need this functional urgently you could raise an issue here https://github.com/pmlmodelling/nctoolkit/issues and I can quickly add it to the dev version

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cdo package to do this using a wild card in the input file name.  I've only tested it with a small number of files though, there is a caveat in that you might hit a system limit on the number of open files.

```
from cdo import *
cdo=Cdo()
cdo.ensmean(input='*.nc',output='ensmean.nc')
```

This is basically the equivalent of the command line call to cdo

```
cdo ensmean *.nc ensmean.nc
```

That said, it sounds to me like it would be better to cat them together and then use timmean:

```
cdo.timmean(input=cdo.mergetime(input='*.nc'),output='timmean.nc')
```

which again is the python equivalent to

```
cdo mergetime *.nc all.nc
cdo timmean all.nc timmean.nc
```

try both and see which one works/is fastest :-)